# What chips do 3$ wifi dongles use?

Tags: integrated-circuit, wifi

I saw lots of WiFi dongles withing the price range from $2,50 to $3,50 (eg. [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-150Mbps-150M-USB-WiFi-Wireless-Adapter-Network-LAN-Card-802-11n-g-b-2-4GHz-/171324064404?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27e3b5c294)).
I am current doind a project using a microcontroller with usb, that requires WiFi.
I'm interested what kind of chips are used in these dongles and where can I buy them.

Comment: The cheapest way to buy them in small quantity is to buy entire dongles (and possibly eliminate the connector).  That will save you having to do an RF PCB, too.

Comment: MediaTek chips are popular for this.

Comment: Figuring out what driver a Linux system loads for one (assuming it manages to get it to work) would tell you a lot about what chip it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web site referenced in the auction (www.yunyo-tech.com) reveals that this dongle is using the [Realtek RTL8188](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=228).

Note that **this chip is probably not appropriate for your application** — it is intended for use with a computer as the host. There is no public documentation for the part, and it's quite possible that implementing a driver could require more code space than your microcontroller has available.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily the same chip that's in those dongles, but the ESP8266 is very popular right now and in that price range. Of course, they're not FCC certified, if that matters to you.

Comment: -1 for advocating purchasing electronic components from AliExpress and eBay. Both are terrible places to buy from.

Comment: Maybe for answering a question that is against the sites rules. I actually have gotten decent modules from ebay before (I wouldn't buy something for work from them, but for home projects I see no problem)

Comment: @I.Wolfe I'm not sure why this is against site rules, or where I can even find them to check? Seems a pretty reasonable question imo, as it was about finding an IC to use with a uC.

Comment: It certainly seems like it fits the "Recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them" part of off topic to me.